# Loading script after page fully loaded

Tags: firefox-addon

I am building a firefox addon that loads javascript at every page load. I'm using progress listener function I found on this page:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Progress_Listeners

My problem is that the code seems to execute to early before the page is fully loaded which causes my script to not run. Here is my code.

```js
var PageLoad = {
    browser: null,
    domain:  null,
    oldURL:  null,

    init: function() {
            gBrowser.addProgressListener(urlBarListener,Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_LOCATION);
    },

    uninit: function() {
            gBrowser.removeProgressListener(urlBarListener);
    },

    processNewURL: function(aURI) {
            //if (aURI.spec == this.oldURL)
            //return;

        MyObject.function();

            this.oldURL = aURI.spec;
    }
};

var urlBarListener = {
    locChange: false,

    QueryInterface: function(aIID) {
            if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||
               aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||
               aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))
            return this;
            throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;
    },

    onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) {
            PageLoad.processNewURL(aURI);
    },

    onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus) {},
    onProgressChange: function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {},
    onStatusChange: function(a, b, c, d) {},
    onSecurityChange: function(a, b, c) {}
};

window.addEventListener("load",
    function() {
            PageLoad.init()
    }, false);

var MyObject = {
    function : function() {
            var script = PageLoad.browser.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'url_to_script.js';
            PageLoad.browser.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
};
```

With this code I get this error message on the console:

> PageLoad.browser.getElementByTagName("head")[0] is undefined

If I add a timeout then the script does work intermittently but if the page loads slow I get the same error, here's what works sometimes `setTimeout(MyObject.function, 1000);`

I need a more reliable way of making sure it's executing the script after the page is loaded.

Unrelated, and it doesn't seem to cause any problems but I also see this error message:

> gBrowser.addProgressListener was called with a second argument, which is not supported. See bug 608628.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load javascript at every page load - the best way is subscribing to `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```js
var MyObject  = {
    processDOMContentLoaded: function(doc) {
        var script = doc.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'url_to_script.js';
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById('appcontent');
    if(appcontent != null) {
        appcontent.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
            var doc = event.originalTarget;
            if(doc instanceof HTMLDocument) {
                MyObject.processDOMContentLoaded(doc);
            }
        }, true);
    }
}, false);
```

Have not tested, but should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `onLocationChange` method - but if you look at how the browser behaves, the location in the address bar changes as soon as a connection with the server is established. You should look at state changes instead:

```js
onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus)
{
  if ((aFlag & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP) &&
      (aFlag & Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_IS_WINDOW))
  {
    // A window finished loading
    PageLoad.windowLoaded(aWebProgress.DOMWindow);
  }
},
```

Note that the window that finished loading is explicitly passed to `PageLoad.windowLoaded()` - you will be receiving notifications from different tabs and you cannot assume that the notification comes from the foreground tab.

As to the warning you are getting, just leave out the second parameter in the call to `gBrowser.addProgressListener()`:

```js
gBrowser.addProgressListener(urlBarListener);
```

[`tabbrowser.addProgressListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addProgressListener) only accepts one parameter, unlike [`nsIWebProgress.addProgressListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgress#addProgressListener%28%29) which has a second parameter.

Comment: After further research I ditched the `urlBarListener` function for another one I found online. So I wasn't able to incorporate your suggestion. What you have said does make a lot of sense though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its a great question.
You should use event listener, but carefully, because if you trigger for every page load its can trigger you more than one time (in the worst case about dozens of times).
So how you can do that?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init(); 
},false);

var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
    if(appcontent){
      appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
    }

  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
    var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc

    if (doc.nodeName != "#document") return;
    if (win != win.top) return;
    if (win.frameElement) return;

      alert("the main page has been loaded");

  },
};
```

get notice that we check for the type of the trigger every pageload triggering to prevent multi load.

Comment: This is almost exactly the code I have implemented into the addon that has been working flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: You welome :) and if it is the answer for your question, mark it as answer.

Comment: Thanks, I would but I already selected an answer which is pretty good.. And I might upset Wladimir if I change the answer again :p

Answer (score -1):

The answers that were provided were acceptable but I found yet another solution that works perfectly.

```
var PageLoad = {
init: function() {
    if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
  },
  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
    var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc

    if (doc.nodeName != "#document") return;
    if (win != win.top) return;
    if (win.frameElement) return;

    MyAddon.function();
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
  window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
  PageLoad.init();  
},false);
```

Comment: This is the same as the solution already provided by KAdot (I think that the recommendation to attach the listener to the `appcontent` element instead of the browser is there for compatibility with Firefox Mobile). If you are really only interested in when a page finishes loading then listening to the `DOMContentLoaded` event is sufficient - but you should credit KAdot for that solution instead of duplicating his answer.

Comment: Yes but my solution is the exact answer I need to my problem. While his solution does work, it doesn't work exactly how I needed it too while it loads the function on other resource calls (ajax, javascript includes ect) Which is an easy fix if you know what you're doing in a addon, which I dont. The downvote on my answer looks like it is not a correct solution when it is a correct solution and people who need help in the future might look over this. Just a thought

Comment: Actually, your code has several rather ugly issues that KAdot's code doesn't have - so the downvote is justified.

Comment: Well the code came straight from MDN so please, elaborate on those ugly issues please.

Comment: If i am "duplicating" his answer then how does it have ugly issues.

Comment: Ouch, one of the many abandoned pages on MDN - migrated from Mozillazine and forgotten :-(